# Can you help finding this flowplayer stream link? etvonline.tv

Tags: video, flash, streaming, rtmp

http://www.etvonline.tv/tc/digitalplay.html?video=knz12-0009-tal02

I tried to use URL Snooper, but
Those results are not playable on VLC.

Any help is great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't answer my own question until 8 hours later due to low on reputation, if someone can give me some reputation would be great. 
I found the anwser myself. http://stream-recorder.com/forum/can-you-help-finding-flowplayer-stream-link-t18113.html?p=66750&posted=1#post66750

rtmpdump -r "rtmp://202.167.248.181/" -a "?rtmp://192.168.25.15/vod" -f "WIN 12,0,0,77" -W "http://www.etvonline.tv/js/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.12.swf" -p "http://www.etvonline.tv/tc/digitalplay.html?video=knz12-0009-tal02" -y "knz12-0009-tal02" -o "e:\video.mp4"

Comment: I'll go ahead and answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning the OP's comment into an answer:*

Run this command:

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmp://202.167.248.181/" -a "?rtmp://192.168.25.15/vod" -f "WIN 12,0,0,77" -W "etvonline.tv/js/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.12.swf"; -p "etvonline.tv/tc/digitalplay.html?video=knz12-0009-tal02"; -y "knz12-0009-tal02" -o "e:\video.mp4"
```

Reference: http://stream-recorder.com/forum/can-you-help-finding-flowplayer-stream-link-t18113.html?p=66750&posted=1#post66750

Comment: Didn't want to rep off an answer that's not mine, so made it community wiki.

Comment: Thank you damryfbfnetsi, I didn't have enough reputation to put answer. it works, but the etvonline.tv is very slow.